# Setting up a very simple "turn on device" with Google Home and NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, google-home, dialogflow-es, google-assist-api

So far I've found plenty of guides online that shows how to set up a NodeJS backend, that Dialogflow can talk to. However, Dialogflow was previously API.AI and all the old guides are basically wrong now.

When I try to do this:

```
require('actions-on-google').ApiAiAssistant
```

It will tell me:

> Importing the class name ApiAiAssistant is *DEPRECATED*, use DialogflowApp

But even changing `ApiAiAssistant` to `DialogflowApp` won't work. Here's an example of some Action: https://github.com/greenido/bitcoin-info-action/

As you can see, it has not been updated in a long time, nor does the code actually work (even if I import the intents and so on into Dialogflow).

What I basically want: Give Google Home parameters (like `turn on TV` which would take `TV` as a parameter) and handle that in my NodeJS backend. How would I do something like that? It can be with or without Dialogflow.

Also, is it even possible to say `Hey Google, turn on TV`? So far all examples I've seen it like `Hey Google, launch MY_ACTION` or `Hey Google, ask MY_ACTION to INTENT` which is slow and annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Got some updated code. Works fine with the DialogflowApp:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const Assistant = require('actions-on-google').DialogflowApp;

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const options = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync("./cert.pem"),
    key: fs.readFileSync("./key.pem"),
    ca: fs.readFileSync("./chain.pem")
};

app.post("/google", (req, res) => {
    const assistant = new Assistant({ request: req, response: res });
    let device = assistant.getArgument("device");
    assistant.tell("Turning on " + device);
});

app.listen(5004);
https.createServer(options, app).listen(5005);
```